# Spring WebClient - Purposefully returning bad request

Tags: java, spring-webclient

So I have a WebClient:

```
public Mono<UserObject> getData(String id){
    return webClient.get()
        .uri(/user/getData)
        .header("header", header)
        .bodyValue(id)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(UserObject.class);
}
```

If `/user/getData` returns a bad request, I want the WebClient to return a bad request too. Instead, WebClient throws an internal server error saying that I've got a bad request.

Desired output when executing the WebClient:

```
"status": 400,
"message" : "Bad Request"
```

Actual output:

```
"status": 500,
"message" : "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from GET .../user/getData"
```

Comment: it's logically correct because your 40x error is server error from client's view.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to handle error and return corresponding status

```
public Mono<UserObject> getData(String id){
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/user/getData")
            .bodyValue(id)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(UserObject.class)
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                if (e instanceof WebClientResponseException) {
                    var responseException = (WebClientResponseException) e;
                    
                    if (responseException.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                        return Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(responseException.getStatusCode()));
                    }
                }
                
                return Mono.error(e);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create an error handler which is triggered by the exception and then attach the http error to the response.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614581/11751609) answer  shows how this can be done.